# Vertical lines on my laptop screen

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, laptop, display

This morning I start my laptop as usual I do, surprisingly I found my laptop screen fuzzy or blurred by vertical lines, make difficult to read anything on the screen   These lines are not on a certain part of my screen, those lines are changing positions with screens graphically movent. While I play a video these lines slowly cleared out but when I tried to do other this like open my browser or other application this line keeps coming back and cover the screen with vertical lines. These lines are on the screen from the welcome screen to the last moment of shutting down my laptop, but while I entered in the bios there is no such a line. I don't know why this problem is occurring, is the issue with my monitor or any other things.

Edit: I have added a picture on my display here, and a drivelink with few other pictures.

Google Drive Link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1v36U-pED7pqojPZ5P3_DdvB7p-kE9paI?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: I entered in the bios there is no such a line.   ....   Update BIOS, Chipset driver and Video driver as the issue appears to be driver / software.

Comment: Please add a photo depicting the issue. Has it worked correctly before? The question is tagged both [windows-10] and [ubuntu], does this imply that both OSes are affected?

Comment: Could be an issue with your screen or graphics chip. Does your laptop have it's own graphics chip? Sometimes if the air vents aren't kept clean, or are blocked during usage, the laptop can overheat. The graphics chip could potentially become damaged as well. What make and model is the laptop?

Comment: @gronostaj I have added a photo, It worked before, and now both Ubuntu and Windows are affected

Comment: @John how could I update those?

Comment: I am not entirely clear whether the lines go away in BIOS as you said. If that remains the case, use the manufacturer's update App to update BIOS and Drivers.

Comment: @John in bios no strong vertical lines for sure, but there is a very light kind of pattern which is not perfectly vertical but likely 75 - 80 degrees angled (if I consider vertical lines 90 degrees) which is noticeable while I look at the screen slightly different angle. today I have done some experiments with the Intel graphics command center on windows os, I have adjusted brightness, contrast, hue, a saturation of the display with it. This has reduced the effect of the vertical lines a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

Considering your pictures, it's most certainly a hardware defect. I suppose a gpu-replacement is needed for this one, although without further hands-on testing, it may also affect the screen and or display-connector of your laptop. As both OS's are affected, a software issue is more than unlikely.

Your best bet is to either replace your mainboard and or get a new device depending on age/cost of repair. I suggest you try to take apart your laptop and check if the screen connector tore a bit, and or is slightly misplaced due to mechanical movement when opening the screen / and or handling the notebook. Would be the best practice to first check the connector and go from there. Hopefully it works by placing it back where it belongs (in case of misplacement).

+1 to gronostaj for his notice regarding functionality inside BIOS

Comment: +1, but I'd blame the GPU. LCD is always utilized 100% so it shouldn't work right in BIOS. It could be the cable (BIOS = lower resolution = less bandwidth utilized = less susceptible to issues) but then videos should be _more_ problematic.

Comment: Actually missed the comment regarding the BIOS. In that case I'll agree with you and edit the answer accordingly.